# How can I average a DataFrame filled with dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of the following form:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"06":{'6/6/2006':'5','6/24/2006':'3','8/24/2006':'3'}, "06_01":{}, "06_02":{}, "06_03":{} ,"06_04":{} ,"06_05":{} ,"06_06":{'6/6/2006':'5', '6/24/2006':'3'} ,"06_07":{} ,"06_08":{'8/24/2006':'3'}, "06_09":{} ,"06_10":{} ,"06_11":{}, "06_12":{}})
```

where each column represents all observations in a given year, or year_month period. I would like to average all the dictionary values within each given year_month period.  So the output for `06_06` would be simply 4.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pandas dataframes should not contain other data structures but primitive, atomic types (`int`, `float`, `bool`, `datetime`). Use other non Python collections for such embedded data.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert `df` to float and call `mean`

```
df.astype('float').mean()

Out[738]:
06       3.666667
06_01   NaN
06_02   NaN
06_03   NaN
06_04   NaN
06_05   NaN
06_06    4.000000
06_07   NaN
06_08    3.000000
06_09   NaN
06_10   NaN
06_11   NaN
06_12   NaN
dtype: float64
```